# ChromeCast button with HTML and JavaScript

Tags: chromecast

I'm currently building an website and I would like to have a feature that shows Google Cast. Is it possible with HTML and JavaScript, no complex things.

Answer (score 10):

Simply use the [Chrome Sender API](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers#chrome). From the [Official Integration docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender_integrate):

> **Cast Button**
>
> The Cast button component in your app is handled entirely by the framework. This includes visibility management, as well as click event handling. The button element tag requires the `is='google-cast-button'` attribute for it to be recognized by the framework.
>
> ```
> <button is="google-cast-button"></button>
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can create the button programmatically:
>
> ```
> document.createElement('button', 'google-cast-button')
> ```
>
> You can apply any additional styling, such as size or positioning, to the element as necessary. Use the `--connected-color` attribute to choose the color for the connected receiver state, and `--disconnected-color` for the disconnected state.

Refer to the docs for more details.